# How to decode text file with symbols like \uXXXX?

Tags: sublime-text-3, textfiles

I have a 10 Mb file containing `\uXXXX` characters. How can I decode this with Sublime Text?

Example:
[image]

Comment: You should link to the file or a shorten form of it put it on http://ge.tt because it's not clear what you're talking about

Comment: @barlop, here is the sample - http://pastebin.com/GT6Wtx6z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different things you can try. First and foremost, you need to be using a Unicode font that supports the characters you want to display. [This site](http://www.unicode.org/resources/fonts.html) on unicode.org is a good resource, and Google is quite helpful, as always. If you don't mind using a non-monospace font, Arial Unicode MS comes with Windows and has pretty good coverage. I believe the monospace font Consolas does as well.

Secondly, your operating system needs to be set up to display those characters - most modern ones are, but you may run into issues with some versions and setups of Windows.

In Sublime, make sure you're viewing the file in the correct mode - try **`File -> Reopen with Encoding -> UTF-8`** or **`... -> UTF-16LE`** (or `BE`, you can try both).

So, without knowing the exact contents of your file, how it was generated, and more details about your system, that's about the best I can do. Good luck!

---

**EDIT**

Based on the file you linked, it looks like this is the output of a Python 2 program, as the data seem to be some lists containing unicode strings (I'm a Python programmer, as it so happens). I looked up a couple of the codepoints mentioned, and they're all Cyrillic, so just about any modern font should handle them. The issue is that you're going to need a program to read in the file and translate the individual bytes. In case you're interested, the first full string (from `'` to `'`) is:

> Любимая акция вернулась! В ресторанах Евразия ""3 ролла по цене 1""! С 9 по 12 сентября! Только эти 4 дня! Подробности на evrasia.spb.ru, 88005050145 и 008

Without having the entire file, I can't parse the whole thing for you, but if you're a Python programmer you should know what to do (I'd recommend using Python 3, its Unicode support is much better than 2.x). If not, find the person who generated the file and ask them to decode the bytes for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use the latest version of OSX and there is no problem with Unicode characters display. I've added an example of the file to the comments of my question.

Comment: @LA_ thanks for the link, that solved the problem. See my edit above for what to do.

Comment: Thanks. I am the person who generated the file (=it was bulk downloaded from the Google App Engine), I've already found the way how to decode it with Python. But still I am interested if I can do the same with Sublime (or with built-in Python console).

Comment: @LA_ Sublime Text 3 is built on top of Python 3.3, so all you need to do is paste each string into the console and it'll display the correct encoding. However, this isn't really feasible for a 10MB file, so a plugin would work better.

Comment: can not I access the text of the opened file from the console?

Comment: @LA_ yes, you can. [Here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) is the ST3 API for your perusal. The reason I suggested a plugin is that there are certain things you can't do in the console, like `for`/`if`/`while` loops, function declarations, etc. - basically anything you can't do on one line.

Comment: Thanks. I just haven't found a plugin, which can do needed conversion.

Comment: @LA_ since this is a case for custom parsing of the input, I doubt you'll find a pre-made plugin for it. However, since you've already found a Python solution for translating the file, implementing it in Sublime should be trivial.